# Navigating to a fragment identifier at the bootom of a different page that has HTML5 Video at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

According to the HTML 5 specification, 5.9.8 Navigating to a fragment identifier:

- If there is an element in the DOM that has an ID exactly equal to
  fragid, then the first such element in tree order is the indicated
  part of the document; stop the algorithm here.
- If there is an a  element in the DOM that has a name attribute whose
  value is exactly equal to fragid, then the first such element in tree
  order is the indicated part of the document; stop the algorithm here.

I am using the following code

```
<section id="section0">
<video controls>
<source src="videos/HD.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"'></video>
</section>
<section id="section1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</section>
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
<section id="section9"> Contact Us</section>
```

Where, section9 is where I want to navigate. But for some reason after navigating to section9 initially, I am sent to section0 at the top of the page where my html5 video starts playing.

I am confused as to why this is happening. 
Kindly direct me to solve the same. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your link?

Comment: On which browser are you experiencing it ?

Comment: This issue is faced on chrome and firefox